# Large file uploads stop immediately, 404 error

Tags: 7, files

I am having a weird problem with uploading large files in the Drupal admin's file field. I have the size limit set to 500 MB. I also have the php.ini settings for upload size, post size, and memory all set to 500 MB.

When I upload a smaller file like 50 MB everything works perfectly. If I upload a larger file such as 250 MB then the upload fails immediately and I get a 404 error in the Network tab of the Chrome inspector.

The 404 error is on this URL: http://example.com/file/ajax/field_video_file/und/0/form-tpohUDjq_v0b7OcNhtnQl2TaRc5UcFl9zwJQzI3mlwE

The server is running IIS 7.5.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you replicate this on your localhost? with php 5.3, you can use .htaccess to override the system ini settings. This way, it will be specific to your site. These are the two links should help you with it. On your local host, try with unlimited memory_limit by setting it to -1. [http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php] [http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php]

Comment: .htaccess doesn't work on IIS ;)

Comment: I faced similar issue with nginx. Hope this thread helps someone.

https://www.techpond.in/solved-drupal-cannot-upload-large-files

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.drupal.org/node/97193

> Drupal's limits on upload file size are determined by your server's
>   PHP settings (as well as Drupal specified settings that can be set at
>   Admin > Site Configuration > File Upload). The default values for PHP
>   will restrict you to a maximum 2 MB upload file size.
>
> On the settings page for the upload module, Drupal calculates and
>   displays the maximum file size that you can set based upon two PHP
>   settings: 'post_max_size' and 'upload_max_filesize'. Since
>   'post_max_size' is the limit for all the content of your post, many
>   people choose 'post_max_size' to be a multiple of
>   'upload_max_filesize' to allow multiple files to be uploaded, but this
>   is not essential. The upload module limits the size of a single
>   attachment to be less than either post_max_size, or
>   upload_max_filesize, whichever is smaller. The default PHP values are
>   2 MB for upload_max_filesize, and 8 MB for post_max_size.
>
> Depending on your host, changing these two PHP variables can be done
>   in a number of places with the most likely being php.ini or .htaccess
>   (depending on your hosting situation).
>
> For example, to increase the limit on uploaded files to 10 MB:
>
> ```
> Add the below to the relevant php.ini file (recommended, if you have access). Note that for some hosts this is a system-wide setting.
> ```
>
> However, for hosts running PHP as a CGI script with suexec (for
>   example) you may be able to put these directives in a php.ini file in
>   your Drupal root directory.
>           upload_max_filesize = 10M
>           post_max_size = 10M
>       Add the below to your .htaccess file in your Drupal root directory.
>           php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
>           php_value post_max_size 10M
>
> The PHP documentation states that the memory_limit setting also
>   affects file uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be
>   larger than post_max_size. If this is an issue, see the page on how to
>   [Increase memory available to PHP](https://www.drupal.org/node/29268) (3 methods)
>
> Drupal also allows/enforces its own size limits, independently of what
>   PHP allows. These are found in Drupal 6 at "Administer » Site
>   configuration » File uploads" ( /admin/settings/uploads ). In Drupal 7
>   size limit is controlled on per-field basis. The Drupal settings
>   cannot be larger than those permitted by PHP, but may be smaller if
>   you haven't updated them, so remember to check there also, after
>   updating the php.ini.

Also, make sure your permissions are set correctly from your public/private folders you've set Drupal for file handling. The folders are located at */admin/config/media/file-system*

Comment: Thanks, that took me in a good direction. Now the file appears to upload the whole way, instead of stopping immediately, but now I get a 500 error when the upload is finished and the file does not get placed on the server. I wish I could figure out a way to get more details on that 500 error :(

Comment: Check your permissions.

Comment: I'll modify my answer to include of some the content from the article and some issues that may help in a few minutes.

Comment: I'm having the exact issue.  IIS Server with Drupal 7.  Everything worked fine but recently I started getting the 500 error once the upload completes.  We were having network issues and now that those are resolved, I cannot even get the upload to start.  I immediately get the 404 error for form-...